# Get latest Changeset Number from Path in Build Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

How can i get the latest changeset number of the current build working path in my build workflow?

I'd like do put the changeset number in the build number and the assembly version file of my projekt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to query tfs api version control for history of your item

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh981750.aspx

In most basic form:

```
QueryHistory(
    "ServerPathToYourWorkspace",
    RecursionType.Full,
    1, //number of items returned
)
```

Not sure this is 1:1 in TFS2012 as in it was in 2010 you can get workspace from BuildDetails.Definition.Workspace.Mappings.
You can get access toVersionControlServer through BuildDetails team project collection calling

```
GetService<VersionControlServer>();
```

Comment: There are some difference in TFS2012 but this work great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sequence near the end of the standard template (you will probably want to move it up earlier in the template, before the compile) which is call "If Associate Changesets" inside of that is an Associate Changesets and Workitems activity. The result of that, or out argument, is called associatedChangesets which is an List of Changeset objects which you can then use as an InArgument to your own custom task and accomplish what you want. The Changset number is the Property ChangesetID on each of the Changeset objects.

Comment: But the Associate Changesets could be null, so i can't use it for the build number. Are there any other oportunities?